# Symfony2 : How to flush multiple rows in database in one query

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have 3 rows to insert in a same table which is to be inserted in one go from one query. This is what i tried:

Controller function:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new GlobalSetting();

    $minPLabel = $_POST['minPlayer'];
    $minPValue = $_POST['minPlayerValue'];
    $maxPLabel = $_POST['maxPlayer'];
    $maxPValue = $_POST['maxPlayerValue'];
    $overLabel = $_POST['overs'];
    $overValue = $_POST['oversValue'];

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
       // echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); exit;
        $entity->setKeyName($minPLabel);
        $entity->setValue($minPValue);

        $entity->setKeyName($maxPLabel);
        $entity->setValue($maxPValue);

        $entity->setKeyName($overLabel);
        $entity->setValue($overValue);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('global'));
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('global'));
}
```

This is inserting only the last record, i know some looping will go there but not getting how to execute it. Please help i am stucked. thanx

Comment: if you want to insert 3 records you need to instantiate and persist 3 different `GlobalSetting` class object

Comment: @Matteo right...i get it run. thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use like below

```
    $minEntity = new GlobalSetting();
    $minEntity->setKeyName($minPLabel);
    $minEntity->setValue($minPValue);

    $maxEntity = new GlobalSetting();
    $maxEntity->setKeyName($maxPLabel);
    $maxEntity->setValue($maxPValue);

    $overEntity = new GlobalSetting();
    $overEntity->setKeyName($overLabel);
    $overEntity->setValue($overValue);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($minEntity);
    $em->persist($maxEntity);
    $em->persist($overEntity);
    $em->flush();
```